# target="_blank" en un PDF utilizando PHP

Tags: php, html, pdf, dompdf

Desde un PDF estoy intentando abrir una URL en una nueva pestaña con el atributo `target="_blank"` de la siguiente manera:
 `<div class="cuerpo"><b><a href=" ' . $url . '" target="_blank">HOLA</a></b></div>`

Estoy utilizando DOMPDF para generar el PDF:

> $url = 'https://hola.pdf'; $html = '
>
> ```
>             <head>
>                 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
>                 <link rel="StyleSheet" href="' . $estilos . '" type="text/css">
>             </head>
>             <body>
>                 <img class="imagen" src="' . $imgCabecera . '">
>                 <div class="titulo-principal">
>                     <div class="titulo">COBERTURAS POLIZA</div>
>                     <div class="cuerpo"><b><a href=" ' . $url . '" target="_blank">HOLA</a></b></div>
>                 <div>
>                 <br>
>             </body>
>         </html>';
>
> $html = htmlspecialchars($html, ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401);
> $html = \str_replace(['&lt;', '&gt;', '&quot;'], ['<', '>', '"'], $html);
> $pdf = new DOMPDF();
> $pdf->set_paper("A4", "portrait");
> $pdf->load_html($html);
> $pdf->render();
> ```

Pero no logro que se abra en otra pestaña del navegador, se habré en la misma pestaña.

Comment: Me temo que no es posible hacer eso, ya que el resultado del HTML es interpretado, pero en definitiva es un PDF sin más, el cual no contiene  etiquetas, atributos, ni scripts JS.

Comment: No es posible, por la naturaleza misma de los archivos PDF ([ver aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23475940/5587982))